# Scraping the cheapest Price

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, telegram, telegram-bot

I am trying make a python notifier that notifies me whenever a Giftcard is cheaper than the value I enter inside the code.

1. It should go to the given Allkeyshop website.
2. Click the switch to show the prices including the Paypal fees.
3. Check if the cheapest price is less or more then the value I entered inside the code.
4. If its cheaper it should notify me on telegram.
5. This code should run 24/7 and always keep notifying me.

The Code that I tried:

It kept giving me an error.
Looking for Help

The Code that I tried:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import telegram
from time import sleep

# Set up the Telegram bot
bot_token = "YOUR_BOT_TOKEN"  # Replace with your Telegram bot token
chat_id = "YOUR_CHAT_ID"  # Replace with your Telegram chat ID

# Configure Selenium to use a web driver (e.g., ChromeDriver)
# Make sure you have the appropriate web driver executable in your PATH
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Set up the Chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()


# Navigate to the URL
url = "https://www.allkeyshop.com/blog/xbox-gift-card-germany/?editions=168"
driver.get(url)


#Click the button to show the full Price including the Paypal Fee's
sleep(1)

driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="offer_filters_form"]/div/div[1]/div[5]/div/label[1]').click()

try:
    # Wait for the price element to be visible
    price_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.x-offer-buy-btn-in-stock'))
    )

    # Extract the price text
    price_text = price_element.text

    # Check if the price is below 79.99€
    price = float(price_text.replace("€", "").replace(",", "."))
    if price < 79.99:
        # Send a message to the Telegram chat
        bot = telegram.Bot(token=bot_token)
        message = f"The cheapest price is below 79.99€: {price_text}"
        bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=message)

except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")

finally:
    # Close the browser
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: pls add an error trace log.

Comment: There is not error log.
It just prints "Error: " thats all.
Or do you need anything else ?
Sorry I am a rookie.

Comment: what it prints after `Error: `? i.e. what is the value it's getting for `e` , seems like the error is on posting the message on telegram. when i comment out telegram code i do receive message as `'The cheapest price is below 79.99€: 79.59€'`

Comment: Thats the point.
It LITTERALY just prints "Error:" nothing else for "e".
The Whole print is just: "Error:".

I dont know what I did wrong there.

Comment: not sure how your setup is, if there is exception then `e` should show some message. if you comment out `bot = telegram.Bot(token=bot_token)` and `bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=message)` lines, and put `print (message)`Do your code work okay?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: No @simpleApp It is still not working. I have no Idea why. Is there a way to do it diffrent ? Maybe without using "e" argument ?

Comment: My output is always

C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\AllKeyshop100€Xbox\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\AllKeyshop100€Xbox\main.py 
Error: Message: 


Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: I ran your code minus telegram and works okay for me. Return code  zero is good, when u put `print(message)` do  you see the print ?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\AllKeyshop100€Xbox\main.py", line 26, in <module>
    price_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\AllKeyshop100€Xbox\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 95, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 


|  <-- This happens When I delete "except Exception as e:
    print(message)"

And put "print(message)" instead